# Winerror 10048 when running multiple instances of a Python Selenium application using Chromedriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, networking, tcp

I'm getting the following error when running multiple instances of a Selenium application written in Python on a specific Windows computer:

*"OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/IP address/port) is normally permitted"*

The application is supposed to scrape som data from a website using Chromedriver.

This works fine on another computer that also uses Windows.

Can this be worked around somehow?